# Presta Paypal module causes response to be delayed

Tags: paypal, prestashop

After installing paypal module in presta shop I found my presta to be very very very slow in responding to requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same here: the homepage took 30 seconds longer to load. The problem was the updatePictures function, which is located in modules/paypal/paypal_logos.php.

Apparently, it checks whether the local logo image files are outdated or not. If those files were modified more than one week ago, it attempts to download a more recent version from the web. The thing is, if you don't have write permissions, it will try to download them anyway, at each request.

So, the solution is to give write permissions to modules/paypal/img/logos or if you, like me, don't care to have your logos updated automatically, just exclude the updatePictures function.

I just commented this line out. It's in the getLocalLogos function, found in modules/paypal/paypal_logos.php

> //$this->updatePictures($logo[0], $destination);

I think this behavior should be configurable and I certainly don't want my logo files to be checked at every-single-request.